# TFT LCD panel product no.FH12A-40S-0.5SH(55) (Or Psp 1001 screen) to Xbox VGA

Tags: lcd, vga, tft

I received a broken PlayStation Portable the other day and decided to try and use the 4.3 LCD screen in a custom Xbox 360 console.  [Here](http://www.beyondinfinite.com/lcd/Library/Sharp/LQ043T3DX04.pdf) is the .PDF for the panel. Page 6 and 7 contain the pin-out for the screen and back-light (40 & 4 wire ribbons). [Here](http://gyazo.com/deaed73737bf8c93380aaee23b3d6bb3) is the VGA pinout from the Xbox. As you can see the Xbox VGA requires 1 of each color data signals, while the LCD panel calls for 8 including a LSB and MSB data sig. Can I group the panels colored data sigs. into one so I can attach it to the VGA port?  Any information would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LCD is not compatible in any way with the Xbox 360 VGA.

VGA is an analog system, the LCD screen is digital.

You will require a system which can sample and interpret a VGA signal into a digital form, then output the right LCD signals to drive the screen.  It's not a trivial task and requires in-depth knowledge of both the VGA signalling system and the LCD screen in question.

Comment: The Xbox begins as A/V Composite. Would that make any difference?

Comment: No. You're trying to connect two completely different technologies. Like trying to connect an HDMI TV to a 1980's VCR.